# Activate laptop Webcam in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, laptop, webcam

I can't use my webcam not either in skype or cheese or some other applications. I'm try some internet guide but they haven't effect:

```
➜  ~ sudo lsusb -v | grep Camera              
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Camera Sensor

➜  ~  ls -ltr /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Apr 17 08:36 /dev/video1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Apr 17 08:36 /dev/video0

➜  ~ sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac
```

I'm sure about two months ago the laptop webcam working but now not working. my laptop has not any button/shortcut to disable the webcam. Thank you in advance.